# Fontawesome doesn't work in Html.Raw()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, font-awesome

Fontawesome not works in Html.Raw() function in MVC Razor view. Whats the solution for that?

```
@Html.Raw("<i class=\"fa fa - clock - o\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>:");
```

Comment: Why are there spaces between `fa` and `clock`?

Comment: This spaces made by Visual Studio automatically

Answer (score 3):

When you were written this code on Visual Studio automatically few wrong space might be applied that's why problem cause. Try replacing code bellow I think should be working.

Correct format is-

> class=\"fa fa-clock-o\"

not

> class=\"fa fa - clock - o\"

```
@Html.Raw("<i class=\"fa fa-clock-o\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>:");
```